# Como consigo saber que cliquei em cima de um GameObject no Unity?

Tags: unity3d

estou tentando criar um jogo parecido com fruit ninja, porem sei pouco de programação de jogos, entendo código c#, poderiam me dizer um método de se cliquei em cima de um gameobject?

Comment: O jogo é para dispositivos móveis? Para desktop?

Answer (score 3):

Adicione um Collider(qualquer tipo), **não** marque como "Is Trigger", e adicione esse código no seu script:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    //clicaram em mim
}
```

Ele faz um raycast a partir do ponto da camêra na direção do clique.

Referências:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Answer (score 0):

Você deve adicionar um collider no seu GameObject e um tag.
Após adicionado o collider e o tag, no script vinculado ao seu GameObject você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
function OnCollisionEnter (c : Collision){
   if(c.gameObject.tag == "meuObjeto") {
     // Faça alguma coisa.
   }
}
```

Comment: Resposta incompleta, não está tratando da parte do clique, e o evento que deve ser utilizado pra tratar um clique não é esse...

Comment: Verdade. Me equivoquei um pouco, o OnCollisionEnter é para tratar colisões entre objetos. Obrigado pela correção.